# how to properly sort a column that shows value as string but based on integer rank in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using datable to sort my table of a column called rank. Now my rank is represented as integer (1-4) in the database. So for example, I have rank 1 that is Bronze, rank 2 that is Silver, rank 3 that is Gold and rank 4 that is Platinum. The highest rank is platinum. So I want it to display on the table that shows the order from highest rank to lowest.

On my script I would write something like below:

```
$("#report").DataTable({
                "searching": false,
                "pageLength": 25,
                "processing": true,
                "order": [2, 'desc'],
                dom: "lBfrtip"
            });
```

This would not display in the right order as the datatable is sorting the column based on alphabetically. So my column will output the order like:

```
Silver
Platinum
Gold
Bronze
```

I want it to be:

```
Platinum
Gold
Silver
Bronze
```

Is it possible to modify this to make it to work (without modifying the server side script)?

Comment: I've never used it, but i think this page explains the whole thing: https://www.datatables.net/blog/2016-06-16

Comment: Would it be more efficient to sort the order from my sql query instead on relying the plug in?

Comment: depends if you make use of the features that allows clients to reorder stuff themselves or not. ifnot then i guess you could do it in your `SELECT` query. It would def be faster / less overhead.